# How can i change the cell colour in ANTD table according to the value?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have table and i want change the colour of that cell based on the value.
if value of cell is more than 50 text colour of cell should be red. if cell value is less than 20 then green.So configuration of cell should be based on the condition ..I'm attaching the code here. I'm new to coding and this is the first project. much appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Divider, Table, Tag } from 'antd'
import report from './report.json'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import {
  Header,
  Header1,
  TableSchema,
  Header2,
  C1,C2,C3,C4,Rank
} from './style.js'

const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;

const data = [
  {
    key:'0',
    class: 'All India',
    circle: 'All India',
    subHeader1: 12,
    subHeader2: 66,
    subHeader3: 32,
    subHeader4:52,
    subHeader5: 74,
    subHeader6: 32
  },
  {
    key:'0',
    class: '1',
    circle: 'GUJ',
    subHeader1: 42,
    subHeader2: 16,
    subHeader3: 70,
    subHeader4:12,
    subHeader5: 54,
    subHeader6: 33
  },
  {
    key: '1',
    class: '1',
    circle: 'DEL',
    subHeader1: 32,
    subHeader2: 66,
    subHeader3: 74,
    subHeader4:22,
    subHeader5: 42,
    subHeader6: 31
  },
]
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(report)
    const items = report.data.columns.map(item =>
      (
        item.subHeader ? (<ColumnGroup title={item.columnName}>
          {
            item.subHeader.map((it,index) => (
              <Column title={it.name} dataIndex={it.dataIndex} key="2" />
            ))
          }
        </ColumnGroup>) : <Column title={item.columnName} dataIndex={item.dataIndex} key="age" />
      )
     )
    return(
      <div id="root">
        <Header>
          <Header1>
            {report.header.displayName}
          </Header1>
          <Header2>
            DATA - {report.header.month}
          </Header2>
        </Header>
        <TableSchema>
        <Table dataSource={data} bordered title={() => `${report.header.displayName}` }>
          {items}
        </Table>
        </TableSchema>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Customise table cells:**

You can change color of specific cell(s) as per certain conditions, you need to target `render` attribute of `columns`.

For example, if cell `Amount` is more than `50`, then render cell color as `red`, otherwise `green`.
[image: antd-table-cell-color]

```
render(text, record) {
          return {
            props: {
              style: { background: parseInt(text) > 50 ? "red" : "green" }
            },
            children: <div>{text}</div>
          };
        }
```

**Columns array**

```
 columns: [
      {
        title: "Date",
        dataIndex: "date",
        width: 200
      },
      {
        title: "Amount",
        dataIndex: "amount",
        width: 100,
        render(text, record) {
          return {
            props: {
              style: { background: parseInt(text) > 50 ? "red" : "green" }
            },
            children: <div>{text}</div>
          };
        }
      },
      {
        title: "Type",
        dataIndex: "type",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        title: "Note",
        dataIndex: "note",
        width: 100
      }
    ]
```

---

**Customise table rows:**

If you want to change the color of rows rather than cells, then you need to target props `rowClassName`

[image: antd-table-row-color]

```
 <Table
        bordered
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={this.data}
        rowClassName={(record, index) => (record.amount > 50 ? "red" : "green")}
      />
```

**css**

```
.red{
  color: red; 
}
.green {
   color :green; 
}
```

**data**

```
data = [
    {
      key: 0,
      date: "2018-02-11",
      amount: 40,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      date: "2018-03-11",
      amount: 243,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      date: "2018-04-11",
      amount: 98,
      type: "income",
      note: "transfer"
    }
  ];
```

here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-59100322-table-cell-color?file=index.js), let me know

**Update 01:**

OP asked in the comment section: **I want to change the colour for "may" subheader in each column**

**Answer:** Feel free to play around the code to match your expectations. In your case, you need something like this ?

`background: it.name === "May" ? (parseInt(text) > 50 ? "#08AE4E" : "#f54840") :"#000"`

[image: custom-pic]

Comment: i have used mapping for columns, how can i apply this to a specific column ?

Comment: you have specified columns , in my case it has subcolumns under columns. how to apply this to a  specific subcolumn?

Comment: can you create a code sandbox ? I will look into that? I saw you have `reports.json` I don't have any idea about that. That's why I just wrote the code of how to do it in ant design using some demo datas. It was just for the idea.

Comment: check this codesandbox link. i want change colour for "may" subheader in each column.https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-framework-gzg0d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It's simple? `background: it.name === "May" ? (parseInt(text) > 50 ? "#08AE4E" : "#f54840") :"#000"`

Comment: very helpful answer. thank you. it would be EVEN better with an example showing how to also update cell of the header ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Also based on the cell content, you can change the backgroundColor like that:

```
  {title: "Status",
  dataIndex: "status",
  render(text, record) {
    return {
      props: {
        style: {
          background:
            record.status === "send"
              ? "red"
              : record.status === "in process"
              ? "green"
              : "white",
        },
      },
      children: <div>{text}</div>,
    };
  },}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we try to add style attribute on td in antd table with this props based approach we might run into the problem of re-rendering of components.

By using onCell method we might resolve the issue of re-rendering of components if there are complexity involved.

Reference to use onCell: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33093

My example to add dynamic style:

```
const columns = [{
          dataIndex: 'name',
          onCell: (text, record) => {
            const checkCase = text['name'].length > 50 ? 'red' : 'green;
            return {
              ['style']: {background: checkCase},
              className: 'example-class-in-td',
            };
          },
        ]
```